# Typescript assert array of values is NonNullable

Tags: typescript

I have a set of values on an object that are possibly `null` or `undefined`. I want to throw an error if they are, and have Typescript know that they are not `null` or `undefined` if the values exist. I can do this:

```
if (!params.target || !params.value) {
  throw Error('Missing parameters')
}

const connection: { target: string; value: string } = {
  target,
  value
}
```

but there are multiple values to check throughout the function and I would rather use a single helper function to do the null checks. I am able to use `asserts` to verify that a single value is not `null` or `undefined` like this:

```
function checkMissingParams<T>(value: T): asserts value is NonNullable<T> {
  if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    throw Error(
      'Missing parameters'
    );
  }
}
```

and then in my main function do:

```
checkMissingParams(params.target)
checkMissingParams(params.value)


const connection: { target: string; value: string } = {
  target,
  value
}
```

However, what I'd really like to do is something like this:

```
function checkMissingParams<T>(
  values: T[]
): asserts values is NonNullable<T[]> {
  const everyValueExists = values.every(
    value => value !== undefined && value !== null
  );
  if (!everyValueExists) {
    throw Error(
      'Missing parameters'
    );
  }
}
```

and then

```
checkMissingParams([params.target, params.value])
```

but when i try this I get:

```
Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

when I try to do:

```
const connection: { target: string; value: string } = {
  target,
  value
}
```

Is it possible to use `asserts` over an array of values like this?

Comment: I would recommend using something like ArkType or Zod for this

Comment: Your code doesn't work because type guard/assertion functions only narrow the reference passed in, not its contents.  You're passing in an array literal so you necessarily lose access to it immediately.  If you want to narrow multiple props in `params`, then you'll need to pass in `params` itself.  Maybe you can refactor to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Nrj4zN)?  If that fully addresses the question I'll write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That makes sense in terms of why my initial `asserts` doesn't work. Your refactor works for this specific case, thanks. I've updated it slightly to also check whether the obj exists. If I did have an array of unrelated values that I wanted to check (i.e. not from the same object), would there be a way to handle that? Best I can think of so far would be to reduce the array into an object and use Object.keys to get the props.

Comment: You can only narrow one input.  If you pass in an array then you need to hold onto that array.  That would require `const myArr = [val1, val2]; narrow(myArr);` and then subsequent accesses would need to be `myArr[0]` and not `val1` for you to see the narrowing.  It's not any better than a function that returns new values like `const myArr = narrow([val1, val2])` and there's no way to force TS to propagate narrowings to multiple variables.  So, should I answer the question with my suggestion from the first column?  Or write that it's not possible in general and why?

Comment: Your suggestion from the first column was helpful as I was able to use that to do what I wanted, but a direct answer to the question would probably be why it's not possible in general and why

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not generally possible.

Functions that return [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (e.g., `x is T`) or [assertion predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) (e.g., `asserts x is T`) are only able to narrow the apparent type of the *specific single argument* corresponding to the parameter named in the predicate.  If you have `declare function f(x: any): asserts x is T` and a variable `foo`, then `f(foo)` will narrow the type of `foo` to `T`.  (This also works for properties, like `f(foo.bar)` will narrow the type of `foo.bar` to `T`.)

But such a narrowing does *not* propagate to all other values whose type logically depends on the narrowed variable.  If you have `const baz = foo` then `f(baz)` will narrow `baz` but have no effect on `foo`.  If you have `const qux = [foo]` then `f(qux[0])` will narrow `qux[0]` but have no effect on `foo`. Furthermore, [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Literal) like `[foo]` that you don't first assign to some variable or property are inaccessible after use.  So if you call `f([foo])` then it not only has no effect on `foo`, but the value it *does* narrow is gone now.  If you rewrite `[foo]` you have a new array literal that has no relationship to the one you passed to `f`.

So `checkMissingParams([params.target, params.value])` cannot do anything to `params.target` or `params.value`, nor do you have access to the array literal after the call.  You could assign it to a new variable like `const arr = [params.target, params.value]` and then call `checkMissingParams(arr)`, but after this you'd need to reference `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` to see the results.  That is strictly worse than just writing a function to return a narrowed array, and writing `const arr = getCheckedMissingParams([params.target, params.value])`.

It's not possible, sorry.

---

Of course for the particular example, the things you want to narrow are all properties of the same `params` object.  That means you could have the function take `params` as an argument, along with an array/list of keys, and then it narrows the type of `params` as a result:

```
function checkMissingProps<T, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T,
    ...props: K[]
): asserts obj is T & { [P in K]-?: NonNullable<T[P]> } {
    const everyValueExists = props.map(k => obj[k]).every(
        value => value !== undefined && value !== null
    );
    if (!everyValueExists) {
        throw Error(
            'Missing parameters'
        );
    }
}
```

Here the object of type `T` is narrowed to `T & { [P in K]-?: NonNullable<T[P]> }`, which is both a `T` and additionally all the properties in the key list `K` are no longer nullable.  This has the effect you wanted:

```
params; // {target?: string; value?: string }
params.target.toUpperCase(); // error, possibly undefined
checkMissingProps(params, "target", "value");
params; // {target?: string; value?: string} & {target: string; value: string}
params.target.toUpperCase(); // okay
params.value.toLowerCase(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.2.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawLIwM54xgDmACgE5wAOeAPACoA0iA0omgB5RpgAmeiTGgCecYInoA+ABQAoRAsRwARgCsAXBMbzFAOn1VKNTSwDaAXVkBKTQEMCaclAErVifBMQAyRAG9EpqTuSCzmALQA-JoAcgjRIAA2CbbKCWgMgeaSiAC+fjoKEAh4UOwAbo7CAGq2CSBoAKIc+M6IALyIhtR4ugC2tlTSmO3ZrqaY5la6aBXkwnKKi4hltfUjy6toiACEbR3gvGjARGi83j4rdVu7HWCJCQWIVgDcjzDi0tszlTVXTS14Kz5JaKKAoSgAd0QDXIlHICxBSwA5LgCERiJ1bORbL00NxyHgkY9Fi9HjlZOTZKBILAEIgOAzpFQsTi8Jp-FAscQ8VFECVyOjmJd6rz+ejckDfI9mdjenhnogAPSKvyc8jcqCiqACkgK4VoLU6jHkxYy1m6NUai1wACqVCojgAwvY0NIXkqVY44cwqHA0alhIgDkcTrxHqgMDh8IQSBRukyWXLmAAiS145Mp-XJ0mmxPyj2qrk8zRi3UbK6G9F5Hy+NNQEva9F6zYNo0mxRmuUWotQa12h3kZ14V3u5VKTC2YTSvO6fXWgAycAhTpdboVY7gE6nlLAOLQeGZEC2ACkILUAF7AxREfHAWxHzwczT0XKyR6HCDJchbanQeBIYBpA4OwwGEGxEHsYcnAEDh3AEehXkeXdcQPe8tgADSvEEPy-LYijAEpEGAOA4BA4RXkRIjpGIuAc0RGiC3oMkkL3VCHwATSwpYcKxPDilKGj2UQZRbHPMjcgo+jqJI3QRPPOiQRo2TRMY5iWJQw8tk4qVKJ479kH4oiSLIySQXwwiRPIdojLgUylkAyyFKWSz1xVJjKJo1yINAt9KPM0oAEcQFgjpTBo8w7MWQCgo4UwAAZJkixQYviiLVI8kivNsHzFkpRZkP3TTEAALS4xY9L4giBOM7zyOJRRAKfGyJSShRpCahiclHFVazI9tFMygtsqnXKKSAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but sadly it breaks type assertion because ts can't infer what happens in `checkMissingParams`.

You can cast the types to tell the ts compiler that you know the values are guaranteed to be strings.

```
const connection = {
  target as string,
  value as string
}
```

or you can rewrite `checkMissingParams` to return type safe values:

```
function checkMissingParams<T>(
  values: (T | undefined | null)[]
): asserts values is NonNullable<T[]> {
  const everyValueExists = values.every(
    value => value !== undefined && value !== null
  );

  if (!everyValueExists) {
    throw Error(
      'Missing parameters'
    );
  }

  return values as T[];
}

const [target, value] = checkMissingParams([params.target, params.value]);
```

Comment: This doesn't assert anything : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawLIwM54xgDmACgIYBO5AtngDwAqAfABQBQiiAbuQDYg0eAFyJWjRAB9E4ACZpgRNLKmIwIPnwCUAbQC67LaPIE0lKHh79Bl-IgByCexr7kARnzRN9zRAG9OZAQ8KEQ0bjMATwA1azQAUQAPfAtEAF4rASEAOnCoji4uXiz032LBRABCNIy5BSUVADJGzIrqjPVNQK0AbnZAmGAxSrzKGLiklLwtf0CuKBRKOAB3RHjKJcoCwq4AclwCImJEAAcqWjQoMzxducRewIBffq5KS5BKJHKhRBNERn0fWe7HkEFcbyCYBCiGAcDgwj8sLgAH5RCFKEdHn12KgMDh8IQSBRqHRWDokXoHuwkewAPS0gB6yPYQA

Comment: No, but if you use the returned values instead, those are asserted as strings `const [target, value] = checkMissingParams([params.target, params.value]);`. This is just another way of accomplishing type safety

Comment: Yeah I don't want to use `as` unless absolutely necessary - would rather have the verbose `if` checks. Also if I'm using `asserts` I can't return a value from the function, and I don't want to either as again that will be handing unnecessary complexity to what I want to do.